CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture not working on iOS 17.6?
I used CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture in my .NET MAUI App (8.0.70)
But, on iOS 17.6 it seems like I can‘t use this anymore und my App crashes when I use this. When I removed it to test I could start my App on my local iPhone with iOS 17.6
Was there anything changed that disallows it? Anything I can use instead? What I wanted to do is use the same culture initially as is the current locale/culture setup on the device. I can switch locales internally in my app (just as a background information)

what exception causes the crash?  Have you searched for known bugs?

My problem is, that it only occurs on my iPhone which has the new iOS. Don’t know how to determine the problem. Currently, it is also only guesswork. When this line is included, the App does not start anymore - well, it is in a ViewModel that is called during Startup. But, when I exclude this line, the App starts just fine. I had the same problem when using Preferences.Get(…) instead of Preferences.Default.Get(…) which now works. Hard to find out

Do you have any exception handling in your code?  That is generally the first step in debugging something like this

This question might sound stupid to you, but is a serious question: How should I implement Exception Handling, because the trouble is on my real device. First of all since May I was developing my App further just with testing on Simulator with (iOS 17.2). Then I tried to get it on my local iPhone and determined it was not working anymore on it and crashed during startup. I checked what changes there have been and thought it was solely the  DevExpress update from 23.2.5 to 24.1.4, but it turned out there was more. I could run everything Release on Simulator, but on real Device still crashing

Sentry didn’t give me good hints and always missing lines of Code. Then I tried a different approach und created a completely new project and did add my Views etc. in small steps. When I added my Settings Page it started to crash the App on Startup. When I commented out and back in Single lines, it turned out that Preferences.Get(…) caused a crash. I replaced it with Preferences.Default.Get(…) and it worked. Same with CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture and it crashed. When I replaced it with the Code I shared, it worked again. But, don’t really know why it started to be not working: iOS Upda

Well, as my assumption currently is that in later iOS versions like 17.x something changed in the native API so that e.g. retrieving the InstalledUICulture is not working anymore as follows.
Therefore, I did my own implementation as below to replace the following snippet:
// Retrieve the installed UI Culture of the system
CultureInfo systemCulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;

// Extract the two-letter ISO language code from the UI Culture
string systemLanguageCode = systemCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;


For my App, I tried a different approach and wanted to retrieve this information with platform specific code an a general Service interface
Non platform specific Service Interface:
namespace MyApp.Localization
{
    internal interface ILocalizationService
    {
        string GetCurrentSystemLanguage();
    }
}


Platform specific implementation in a file Platforms\iOS\LocalizationService_iOS.cs:
using Foundation;
using MyApp.Localization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp.Platforms.iOS
{
    public class LocalizationService_iOS : ILocalizationService
    {
        public string GetCurrentSystemLanguage()
        {
            var systemLanguage = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];
            var currentCulture = new CultureInfo(systemLanguage);

            return currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        }
    }
}


Platform specific implementation in a file Platforms\iOS\LocalizationService_Android.cs:
using Foundation;
using MacroOptimizerApp.Localization;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp.Platforms.Android
{
    public class LocalizationService_Android : ILocalizationService
    {
        public string GetCurrentSystemLanguage()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}


MauiProgram.cs to register the platform specific services via ConfigurePlatoformServices(...):
namespace MyApp
{
    public static partial class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            ...

            
            ConfigurePlatformServices(builder);

            return builder.Build();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// // Defines a method that will be implemented in the platform specific files
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">Builder to register platform specific services</param>
        static partial void ConfigurePlatformServices(MauiAppBuilder builder);
    }
}


Platform specific partial class Platforms\iOS\MauiProgram.iOS.cs:
using MyApp.Localization;
using MyApp.Platforms.iOS;

namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Partial class of the MauiProgram file in the same namespace to configure just the platform-sepecific Services
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class MauiProgram
    {
        static partial void ConfigurePlatformServices(MauiAppBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationService, LocalizationService_iOS>();
        }
    }
}


Platform specific partial class Platforms\Android\MauiProgram.Android.cs:
namespace MyApp
{
    public static partial class MauiProgram
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Partial class of the MauiProgram file in the same namespace to configure just the platform-sepecific Services
        /// </summary>
        static partial void ConfigurePlatformServices(MauiAppBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationService, LocalizationService_Android>();
        }
    }
}


Maybe you miss the topic Can I answer my own question? from the help center

It was nothing I knew before when I asked this question, but found out afterwards. I clicked on the answer Button to share my findings. Was it  wrong to do this? The description you shared pretty much reads the same.
